# Source of "miscarriage of justice"

Tags: etymology, expressions, word-usage, figurative

What may be the source of the phrase "miscarriage of justice"?

I keep hearing this phrase being used for cases where an innocent has been convicted. While the phrase paints quite a picture, I'm not sure as to how it has come to be used.

Note: I've checked on its wiki page but there is nothing to suggest its origin.

Comment: It was not originally intended to paint a picture, anymore than the phrase "commercial intercourse."

Comment: The learned jury has conceived and conceived but hasn't delivered yet.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/miscarriage

Comment: The etymology makes it clear that the use of the term to mean "mistake" predates the medical use by 80 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a set phrase, from ***[1875](http://1875)*** (Etymonline):

***Miscarriage:***

> - ***1580s, "mistake, error;***" 1610s, "misbehavior;" see miscarry + -age. Meaning "untimely delivery" is from 1660s. ***Miscarriage of justice is from 1875.***
> - ***(now rare except in miscarriage of justice)*** A failure; a mistake or error. [from 16thc.]
>
>   - ***1590, Edmund Spenser, The Faerie Queene, III.ii:*** - *for feare least blame / Of her miscarriage should in her be fond, / She wist not how t'amend, nor how it to withstond.* (Wiktionary)

***[Miscarriage justice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miscarriage-of-justice):***

> - a situation in which someone is punished by the law courts for a crime that they have not committed:
>     *Many people oppose the death penalty because of the possibility of miscarriages of justice.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)